# How to disable automatic session closure in Selenium+Firefox?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm making a parser bot, running on Selenium+Firefox in Python. It is necessary to constantly work from under one session, but when idle after some time, the channel closes, and with it the session:

```
selenium_1  | 12:49:14.243 INFO [ActiveSessions$1.onStop] - Removing session 1bbe1550-852e-4602-bfc2-532d67d3fbbf (org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService)
selenium_1  | 1620737354261     Marionette      INFO    Stopped listening on port 35195
selenium_1  | 
selenium_1  | ###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
```

How to disable automatic session closure, or how to resume a closed session?

Comment: Are you using RemoteWebdriver? If so, you can invoke it with the sessionTimeout flag: `$>java -jar /path/to/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -sessionTimeout 57868143`